# DNS Server Routing

Tags: ubuntu, domain, domain-name-system

I have a local DNS server setup to resolve things like myserver.mydomain.com myserver2.mydomain.com to specific internal servers. Now if i map those subdomains externally to the external ip of my local DNS, is there a way that I could get those to map so that they work externally as well as internally without some type of VPN?

Comment: Can you clarify what your current configuration is?  And what DNS software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but since the public DNS hierarchy will not know about "mydomain.com", you'll need to configure the client to use your own DNS server as resolver.

BIND can do both resolver (for your client) and authority (for publishing zone *.mydomain.com) at the same time. You can use BIND views to "restrict" the zone to your client only (and not other Internet hosts).
If you use a DNS server other than BIND, one that splits resolver and authority, you'll need to also tell your resolver "query  for anything like *.mydomain.com".